# Javascript + Bootstrap Image Gallery not loading

Tags: javascript, image-gallery

I have a problem on loading the following page, which is a working image gallery that I included bootstrap codes on head.
http://portaloficial.com.br/teste/teste.php

Can anyone help me out?

ps: the original gallery script is here http://sye.dk/sfpg

Comment: Can you give an example of your implementation code?

Comment: Very few SO users are going to click on strange links to look at your code. Post the relevant parts in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should try and debug your code, and present a detailed description of the problem. People trying to answer your question shouldn't have to go to unknown sites to find out the problem.

Your website is showing this error on the console:

```
jQuery(...).preloader is not a function
```

Probably you need to include some script that extends jQuery with this method, because from what I can tell, it's not defined in the standard jQuery version.